# Redirect with query string in Asp.Net Core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, http-redirect

I'm calling an action name `PaymentStatus` with a query string and I'm binding query string parameters with my model.

Here it is.

```
[HttpGet("PaymentStatus")]
    public ActionResult PaymentStatus([FromQuery]ResponseMsgVM res)
    {
        return Redirect(@"http://localhost:27089");
    }
```

Now problem is that I want to Redirect to another URL with the query string of the current request.

Please help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extract current query string from request and include in redirect URL

```
[HttpGet("PaymentStatus")]
public ActionResult PaymentStatus([FromQuery]ResponseMsgVM res) {
    var queryString = Request.QueryString;
    //use querystring to build redirect URL

    return Redirect(@"http://localhost:27089" + queryString);
}
```